# Why Policy works ok for create method, but not not called for update / delete methods?

Tags: laravel

In laravel 10 app I add policy as I read at
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#authorizing-resource-controllers
in constructor of a controller :

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\DTO\TaskDTO;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Http\Requests\CreateTaskRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateTaskRequest;
use App\Http\Resources\TaskResource;
use App\Models\Task;
use App\Repositories\Interfaces\CrudRepositoryInterface;
use App\Repositories\Interfaces\DBTransactionInterface;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;
use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\AnonymousResourceCollection;

class TaskController extends Controller
{
    protected CrudRepositoryInterface $taskCrudRepository;
    protected DBTransactionInterface $dbTransaction;

    public function __construct(CrudRepositoryInterface $taskCrudRepository, DBTransactionInterface $dbTransaction)
    {
        $this->taskCrudRepository = $taskCrudRepository;
        $this->dbTransaction = $dbTransaction;
        $this->authorizeResource(Task::class, 'task'); // This policy method
        ...
```

In routes I see next (I got second 'task' parameter above) :

```
POST            api/showTaskDetailsReport/{taskId} ............................................................................... reports.showTaskDetailsReport › Api\ReportsController@showTaskDetailsReport
GET|HEAD        api/tasks ............................................................................................................................................. tasks.index › Api\TaskController@index
POST            api/tasks ............................................................................................................................................. tasks.store › Api\TaskController@store
POST            api/tasks/filter .................................................................................................................................... tasks.filter › Api\TaskController@filter
PUT             api/tasks/{task_id}/done ................................................................................................................................ tasks.done › Api\TaskController@done
GET|HEAD        api/tasks/{task} ........................................................................................................................................ tasks.show › Api\TaskController@show
PUT|PATCH       api/tasks/{task} .................................................................................................................................... tasks.update › Api\TaskController@update
DELETE          api/tasks/{task} .................................................................................................................................. tasks.destroy ›
```

In policy which I created with command :

```
php artisan make:policy TaskPolicy --model=Task
```

I output log in `__construct` of file `app/Policies/TaskPolicy.php` :

```
<?php

namespace App\Policies;

use App\Enums\PolicyOperation;
use App\Models\Task;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Library\Services\Interfaces\UserCheckAccessInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Access\HandlesAuthorization;

class TaskPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    protected UserCheckAccessInterface $userCheckAccess;

    public function __construct(UserCheckAccessInterface $userCheckAccess)
    {
        $this->userCheckAccess = $userCheckAccess;
        \Log::info(varDump($this->userCheckAccess, ' -1 __construct $this->userCheckAccess::'));
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view any models.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response|bool
     */
    public function viewAny(User $user)
    {
        return $this->getPolicyRule(user: $user, policyOperation: PolicyOperation::VIEW_ANY, task: null);
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\Task  $task
     * @return \Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response|bool
     */
    public function view(User $user, Task $task)
    {
        return $this->getPolicyRule(user: $user, policyOperation: PolicyOperation::VIEW, task: $task);
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can create models.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response|bool
     */
    public function create(User $user)
    {
        return $this->getPolicyRule(user: $user, policyOperation: PolicyOperation::CREATE, task: null);
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can update the model.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\Task  $task
     * @return \Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response|bool
     */
    public function update(User $user, Task $task)
    {
        return $this->getPolicyRule(user: $user, policyOperation: PolicyOperation::UPDATE, task: $task);
    }
    ...
```

and my policy is called ok for create method, but is not called for update or delete method, as I expected.
Does `authorizeResource` method works in other way ?

**ADDITIVE CODE :**
Now in `app/Http/Controllers/Api/TaskController.php` I call methods of `taskCrudRepository` class and call `authorizeResource` in `__construct` of a controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
...

class TaskController extends Controller
{
    protected CrudRepositoryInterface $taskCrudRepository;
    protected DBTransactionInterface $dbTransaction;

    public function __construct(CrudRepositoryInterface $taskCrudRepository, DBTransactionInterface $dbTransaction)
    {
        $this->taskCrudRepository = $taskCrudRepository;
        $this->dbTransaction = $dbTransaction;
        $this->authorizeResource(Task::class, 'task');

    }


    public function store(CreateTaskRequest $request)
    {

        try {
            $this->dbTransaction->begin();
            $task = $this->taskCrudRepository->store(dtoData: TaskDTO::fromRequest($request));
            $this->dbTransaction->commit();

            return response()->json(['task' => (new TaskResource($task))], JsonResponse::HTTP_CREATED); // 201
        } catch (\Error | \Exception $e) {
            \Log::info($e->getMessage());
            $this->dbTransaction->rollback();

            return response()->json([
                'error_message' => $e->getMessage(),
            ], JsonResponse::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR); // 500
        }
    }

    public function update(UpdateTaskRequest $request, int $taskId): JsonResponse
    {
        try {
            $this->dbTransaction->begin();
            $task = $this->taskCrudRepository->update(id: $taskId, dtoData: TaskDTO::fromRequest($request));
            $this->dbTransaction->commit();

            return response()->json(['task' => (new TaskResource($task))], JsonResponse::HTTP_RESET_CONTENT); // 205
        } catch (ModelNotFoundException $e) {
            \Log::info($e->getMessage());
            $this->dbTransaction->rollback();
            throw new ModelNotFoundException($e->getMessage(), JsonResponse::HTTP_NOT_FOUND);
        } catch (\Error | \Exception $e) {
            \Log::info($e->getMessage());
            $this->dbTransaction->rollback();

            return response()->json([
                'error_message' => $e->getMessage(),
            ], JsonResponse::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR); // 500
        }
    }
```

Now method `getPolicyRule` in `app/Policies/TaskPolicy.php` call other class (which injected in `__construct`) :

```
class TaskPolicy
{
    use HandlesAuthorization;

    protected UserCheckAccessInterface $userCheckAccess;

    public function __construct(UserCheckAccessInterface $userCheckAccess)
    {
        $this->userCheckAccess = $userCheckAccess;
        \Log::info(varDump($this->userCheckAccess, ' -1 __construct $this->userCheckAccess::'));
    }

    /**
     * Determine whether the user can view any models.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @return \Illuminate\Auth\Access\Response|bool
     */
    public function viewAny(User $user)
    {
        return $this->getPolicyRule(user: $user, policyOperation: PolicyOperation::VIEW_ANY, task: null);
    }
    ...
    /**
     * Determine whether the user have permanently access to all actions.
     *
     * @param  \App\Models\User  $user
     * @param  \App\Models\Task  $task
     * @return bool
     */
    private function getPolicyRule(User $user, PolicyOperation $policyOperation, ?Task $task): bool
    {
        \Log::info(varDump($policyOperation, ' -1 getPolicyRule $policyOperation::'));

        return $this->userCheckAccess->userTaskHasAccess(user: $user, policyOperation: $policyOperation, task: $task); // Now this userTaskHasAccess always returns true - logics would be added later
    }
}
```

**ADDITIVE CODE # 2:**

At docs I read :

> If you are utilizing resource controllers, you may make use of the
> authorizeResource method in your controller's constructor. This method
> will attach the appropriate can middleware definitions to the resource
> controller's methods.

But adding method in controller :

```
    public function update(UpdateTaskRequest $request, int $taskId): JsonResponse
    {
        $this->authorize('update', [auth()->user(), Task::class]);
...
```

O got 403 error with message

```
This action is unauthorized
```

"update" method of is not event called(I do not see log lines).

In api.php I have :

```
Route::apiResource('tasks', TaskController::class); // I suppose I do not need to add any middleware here as authorizeResource in controller constructor made it.
```

and in app/Http/Requests/UpdateTaskRequest.php :

```
class UpdateTaskRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
...


class UpdateTaskRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: show those controller methods

Comment: My controller methods do not have any policy calling. Have I really to use any. I expected that using of authorizeResource enough and does not need any additive methods

Comment: show those controller method signatures ... also show this `getPolicyRule` method you are calling in your policy methods

Comment: Please read ADDITIVE CODE

Comment: there is no route model binding ... there is no resource to be authorized (`authorizeResources` adds the `can` middleware for each resource method) [refer to the documentation for authorizing via middleware for what that is doing]

Comment: Please give ref to relative part in docs.  I did not find which methods to use

Comment: Please read ADDITIVE CODE # 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did had this same problem before and you just need to change

```
Int $TaskId
```

In both delete and update function in your controller.

This is because your controller function is receiving an integer id while your policy should receive the model instance.

Or you can keep your controller the same but use

```
$this->authorize('update',[auth()->user(), Task::class);
```

After successfuly finding the model instance doing a `find` or `findorfail`

Comment: Sorry I did not understand you post - in my controller I define int taskId var:
`public function update(UpdateTaskRequest $request, int $taskId): JsonResponse`

But you shows the same var , but only with firsr letter uppercase :
`Int $TaskId`

Also I use rge same call of authorize method, as I do:
`$this->authorize('update', [auth()->user(), Task::class]);`


Please detalize how my controller update method would have code?

Comment: What i said is to change the int $taskid you are using in update function to Task $task because your controller function is resiving an intiger id while your policy should receive the model instance  or  use your $this->authorize('update', [auth()->user(), Task::class]); in the update function after finding the model instance like doing a find or findorfail

Comment: I hope i was clear this time